# Why does the order of the selectors in a queryselector call matter?

Tags: javascript

I think i may have found a bug in the `querySelector` function. It seems that the order the selectors are placed affects whether or not the selectors are selected.

I'm trying to select a link using querySelector, and am passing in 3 different selectors, and would like it to select any one of those 3, unfortunately, sometimes it won't match the selector even when there is a definite match on the page, unless I rearrange the order of the selectors in the querySelector function.

Test link that i want to match:
   `<a  href="https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/coyotes?source=ftp"><span>#Coyotes</span> 60 recent posts</a>`

This function returns `null`:

```
document.querySelector("a[href$='?source=fttp']","a[href$='?source=ftp']","a[href^='/topic/']")
```

This function call matches the link

```
document.querySelector("a[href$='?source=ftp']","a[href^='/topic/']","a[href$='?source=fttp']")
```

both calls have the exact same selectors, only in a different order

I've created a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/eB8nv/5/

Can anyone tell me what is going on here, and why the order of the selectors sent to the querySelector function matters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelector()` only takes one parameter.
You can't do that.

Instead, you need to pass a single string with three comma-separated selectors.

Comment: Or use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) instead

Comment: @kei: That won't help at all.